# Search into different strings

Tags: java, string, loops

I have the next situation, i have a string like xml, I would like to search into this String to the second car_id (`<car_id>12345678</car_id>`) and get the value
if not avaible to search the car_type (`<car_type id_1="2" id_2="32">55555</car_type>`) 
i tried  the next code see below but is not working fine. is there better way to do/loop the Strings? thanks and thanks to Stackoverflow

Strings:

```
<car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_id>12345678</car_id></car>

<car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_type id_1="2" id_2="32">55555</car_type></car>
```

Code:

```
 String carId = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("<car_id>")+9, input.lastIndexOf("</car_id>"))
    String carType= input.substring(input.indexOf("<car><car_type>")+84, input.indexOf("</car>"))
```

Comment: use XML parsing API.

Comment: I have strings no xml

Comment: you can create XML from string as well in memory. [Read more...](http://www.journaldev.com/1237/java-convert-string-to-xml-document-and-xml-document-to-string)

Comment: Don't start parsing xml with string operations, save yourself the pain and use something like xpath

Comment: Use Pattern Matching to find the string

Comment: indexof works to do the job but not fine, i would to search into different strings

Comment: the numbers u use are the prob... be good in maths.. it would work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly discourage you from parsing those strings using regex or indexOf -trickery. Those are always bound to break at some time.

Should your strings that really, really look like xml actually be xml, you could parse the values using xpath. Something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

        String xml1 = "<xml><car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_id>12345678</car_id></car></xml>";
        String xml2 = "<xml><car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_type id_1=\"2\" id_2=\"32\">55555</car_type></car></xml>";

        Document doc1 = stringToDom(xml1);
        Document doc2 = stringToDom(xml2);

        XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("//car/car_id/text()");
        String carId = (String) expr1.evaluate(doc1, XPathConstants.STRING);

        XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("//car/car_type/text()");
        String carType = (String) expr2.evaluate(doc2, XPathConstants.STRING);

        System.out.println("***");
        System.out.println("carId: " + carId);
        System.out.println("carType: " + carType);
        System.out.println("***");

        /* prints 
           ***
           carId: 12345678
           carType: 55555
           ***
        */
    }

    public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) throws SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the car id by using the pattern matching as below. Hope this will help you.

```
String xmlString = "<car_id>12345678</car_id>afhkjasd<car_id>123456789</car_id>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<car_id>)([0-9]{0,})(</car_id>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Index of will do the job:

Original: 
`<car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_id>12345678</car_id></car>`

`<car_dealer><car_id>2</car_id></car_dealer><car><car_type id_1="2" id_2="32">55555</car_type></car>`

Index of Solution:

```
String car_id = input.substring(input.indexOf("<car><car_id>") + "<car><car_id>".length(), input.indexOf("</car_id></car>"));
```

Do same for others.

Good luck!

Comment: The key to doing this: First index of substring is the start string (example: <car><car_id>) plus the length of that string (because you originally get the index of it's first character). As for the end index, you just specify the end string